# Disabling TinyMCE keyboard shortcuts altogether

Tags: tinymce

I've disabled pretty much every button in the visual editor, besides bold and underline. The problem is that the functionality of the other buttons are still there with the keyboard shortcuts. Is there someway to disable the keyboard shortcuts. I don't need them at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really a wordpress question - but have you tried

```
tinyMCE.init({
   ..
    custom_shortcuts : false
});
```

??

(might have a problem with IE though , on which case, you can override them with a foo function.)

```
function disableShortcuts(){
    tinyMCE.get('elm1').addShortcut("ctrl+b","nix","foo");
    tinyMCE.get('elm1').addShortcut("ctrl+i","nix","foo");

}
```

after that you will need to add  the "foo" command to tinMCE:

```
tinyMCE.init({
   //your other stuff
        oninit : "disableShortcuts",
        setup : function(ed) {
                  // Register foo command  shortcuts
                  ed.addCommand('foo', function() {
                  //foo function does null
                  });
               }
    });
```