# How to disable TinyMCE 4 keyboard shortcuts

Tags: tinymce, visual-editor

I want to disable **all** TinyMCE 4 keyboard shortcuts. I have looked around for a workable solution but only realised how poor the TinyMCE documentation is.

I did find one [answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/38313/24875) but either I do not know how to apply it or it doesn't work with TinyMCE 4 (that was introduced with WP 3.9+).

Anyone with reasonable TinyMCE and WP knowledge who can crack this?

Answer (score 4):

**Re [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/38313) cited by the OP:**

**Edited to add meta and access and other.**

The `custom_shortcuts` flags mentioned was in tinymce 3.x (see [here](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:custom_shortcuts)) but was removed from 4.x, and on scanning the source nothing equivalent seems to have been substituted.

The foo function method mentioned can still be used. In your theme's "functions.php":

```
add_action( 'wp_tiny_mce_init', function () {
    ?>
    <script>
        function wpse167402_tiny_mce_init(ed) {
            ed.on('init', function () {
                // Note these lists may not be complete & that other tinymce plugins can add their own shortcuts anyway.
                var ctrls = [ 'b', 'i', 'u', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'z', 'y,ctrl+shift+z', 's', 'k', 'Alt+F', 'P', 'shift+e > ctrl+shift+p' ]; // Could add 'x', 'c', 'v'.
                var metas = [ 'b', 'i', 'u', 'z', 'y,meta+shift+z', 's', 'k' ]; // Could add 'x', 'c', 'v'.
                var modKeys = [ 'c', 'r', 'l', 'j', 'q', 'u', 'o', 'n', 's', 'm', 'z', 't', 'd', 'h', 'o', 'x', 'a', 'w' ];
                var accesss = [ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 's', 'c', 'r', 'l', 'j', 'q', 'u', 'o', 'm', 'z', 't', 'd', 'h', 'p', 'x' ];
                var others = [ 'Ctrl+Shift+F', 'Meta+K', 'alt+119', 'Alt+F10', 'Alt+F9', 'Alt+F10,F10', 'Alt+F11' ];
                var i;

                // Overwrite shortcuts with no-op function. Key sequences will still be captured.
                for (i = 0; i < ctrls.length; i++ ) {
                    this.addShortcut('ctrl+' + ctrls[i], '', function () {});
                }
                for (i = 0; i < metas.length; i++ ) {
                    this.addShortcut('meta+' + metas[i], '', function () {});
                }
                for (i = 0; i < modKeys.length; i++ ) {
                    this.addShortcut('alt+shift+' + modKeys[i], '', function () {});
                }
                for (i = 0; i < accesss.length; i++ ) {
                    this.addShortcut('access+' + accesss[i], '', function () {});
                }
                for (i = 0; i < others.length; i++ ) {
                    this.addShortcut( others[i], '', function () {});
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    <?php
});
function wpse167402_tiny_mce_before_init( $mceInit ) {
    $mceInit['setup'] = 'wpse167402_tiny_mce_init';
    return $mceInit;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'wpse167402_tiny_mce_before_init' );
```

**Original answer**

The original answer replaced the editor's `shortcuts` object with a no-op (the `SettupEditor` event is fired before any tinymce instances are created):

```
add_action( 'wp_tiny_mce_init', function () {
    ?>
    <script>
    tinymce.on('SetupEditor', function (editor) {
        editor.shortcuts = { add: function() {} };
    });
    </script>
    <?php
});
```

Although this disables all tinymce's shortcuts, it has the unfortunate side-effect of allowing default browser behaviour, which for `contentEditable` elements (which the tinymce's edit box is marked as) can include various formatting such as ctrl+b, ctrl+i, and ctrl+u (documentation on this is very poor), depending on the browser. A way around this, which makes this answer basically the same as the first, is to just pass on the shortcuts to the original function with the `cmdFunc` replaced by a noop function:

```
add_action( 'wp_tiny_mce_init', function () {
    ?>
    <script>
    tinymce.on('SetupEditor', function (editor) {
        var orig_shortcuts_add = editor.shortcuts.add;
        editor.shortcuts.add = function(pattern, desc, cmdFunc, scope) {
            return orig_shortcuts_add(pattern, desc, function () {}, scope);
        };
    });
    </script>
    <?php
});
```

Comment: Works. However, does the solution linked in the question still work? That approached seem to be the official way of disabling the shortcuts...

Comment: The flag "custom_shortcuts" doesn't exist, so there doesn't seem to be an official way. I've just tried a variation of the "foo" command way given, and it would work, though you'd have to specify each shortcut you want to disable, and the shortcut commands would still capture the key sequence (so eg "ctrl+b" wouldn't bring up your bookmarks in Firefox). I could update the answer with that method if you like...

Comment: Yes, please do update your answer with this alternative solution so we have as complete answer as possible for this bounty. When considering performance, do both solutions carry the same weight?

Comment: Ok, added a version of the alternative solution. Also removed "crude" from the original solution seeing as it might put people off! Re performance, it's negligible really, though the first solution would win as nothing gets executed.

Comment: Just a note: It appears the first code works in Firefox but does not work in Chrome (and possibly other browsers). However, the second solution works perfectly fine.

Comment: Oh so it doesn't - not much use then! It seems that because the edit box is `contenteditable`, certain browsers (chrome as you say & also IE) will implement their own shortcuts to do certain formatting. I'll update the answer, demoting the first solution, soon when I get more info... Thanks!

Comment: For some reason the re-answer doesn't work for me and I can't figure out why. The "original answer" works, but it disabled all shortcuts, which is not what I want.

Comment: @sven - later versions of tinymce have changed to using `meta` and `access` so added them, so the "re-answer" should now work for you and you can customize if you don't want certain shortcuts disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Id just thought id share: I am using tinymce in the frontend via wp_editor() I have unset the keyboard shortcuts like insert/edit link etc or help and i am using:

```
<?php
                            $content = $posted['rm_details'];
                            $editor_id = 'rm_details';
                            $settings = array(
                                'media_buttons'     => false,
                                'drag_drop_upload'  => false,
                                'textarea_rows'     => '15',
                                'tinymce' => array(
                                    'content_css'               => get_template_directory_uri() . '/styles/tinymce5.css',
                                    'toolbar1'                  => 'bold,bullist,numlist',
                                    'toolbar2'                  => '',
                                    'paste_word_valid_elements' => 'p,b,strong,li,br',
                                    'plugins'                   => '',
                                ),
                                'quicktags'         => false
                            );
                            wp_editor( esc_textarea( $content ), $editor_id, $settings ); ?>
```

Setting 'plugins' => '', seems to do the trick.

Also this seems to enable the default browser shortcuts for me,

Thanks

Nathan